# Needing to display Angular UI Bootstrap progressbar with text behind the progressbar

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am needing to display text behind the progressbar centered with the progress bar advancing over the top of it. If it is a time consuming operation only a small portion of the text is displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

```
'<uib-progressbar title="{{row.entity.dollarsShipped  | currency}} / {{row.entity.price  | currency}}" type="success" max="row.entity.price" value="row.entity.dollarsShipped"><span >{{row.entity.dollarsShipped  | currency}} / {{row.entity.price  | currency}}</span></uib-progressbar>
```

[image]

Comment: so what exactly do you want to do with the text? even if the progress-bar won't cut it, you will still barely see it with that light gray background.

Comment: @svarog I was thinking of changing the text color to black.